# .hack//G.U. Last Recode game order

Tags: .hack-gu

With the release of [.hack//G.U. Last Recode](http://store.steampowered.com/app/525480/hackGU_Last_Recode/) on Steam, I want to pick up playing the .hack franchise but I don't know much about it.

This pack contains 4 games, Rebirth, Reminisce, and Redemption, as well as an all new 4th Volume: .hack//G.U. Reconnection.

Obviously the new one Reconnection is the new one, but what order do I play the others?

Do I need to know anything from any other games in order to start playing this collection?

Comment: @Stormblessed I think you'll find [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12778/is-there-a-need-for-a-suggested-order-tag) relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would play them in the order of .hack//G.U. Vol. 1//Rebirth, .hack//G.U. Vol. 2//Reminisce and .hack//G.U. Vol. 3//Redemption. .hack//G.U. Last Recode will include a brand new volume .hack//G.U. Vol. 4//Reconnection.  This came from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack//G.U._Last_Recode.

Comment: I agree with Ziss, and would add you do not have to play the original 4 .hack games unless you want more lore from their game world. There are references to the first game, but they are not important to know. Edit: By Original 4 games, i mean the first 4 games that came out before G.U. on the PS2.